# How to handle exceptions and specific conditions with the same chunk of Python codes

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

I wonder if there's any way to make Python execute the same chunk of codes if something happen or if there are errors.

For example, I am writing a function which is able to get characters following a colon in a given string, and I want it to do the same thing if *a) there is no colon* or *b) a colon exists but there's no characters following it*. Let's assume there will be at most one colon in a given string.

```
def split_colon(string):
    try:
        ans = string.split(":")[1].strip()
        return ans
    except IndexError or if ans == "":
        return "Hmm, not a word is found"
```

Obviously I am getting a `SyntaxError` in the codes above. How can I achieve my goal *not* by:

```
def split_colon(string):
    try:
        ans = string.split(":")[1].strip()
    except IndexError:
        return "Hmm, not a word is found"
    if ans == "":
        return "Hmm, not a word is found"
    else:
        return ans
```

, which will duplicate the same codes?

Comment: you can use `if criteria: throw ..` but it's better not to use exception handling as control flow

Comment: @shahaf can `if criteria` handle exceptions?

Comment: No, I meant if the `ans` is empty than throw an exception, so handling the exception and the empty case can be the same code block, but as I mentioned it not a good practice, if you know you the pitfalls you better deal with them with criteria checking instead of exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.partition(':')[2]
```

is the way to go. The resulting string will be empty if no colon exists or no character is following the colon.

Comment: Thanks. Should it be `string.partition(':')[2]` as I am getting the characters following the colon though?

Comment: @ytu I was about to point out the same thing, indeed it should be!